# ASPxGridView showing row updating errors

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am trying to display an error message in the edit section of a ASPxGridView when a user has tried to submit invalid data.

I have been looking around and have found one blog that allows me to place an error message in red once it has filed validation by throwing a New InvalidOperationException.

I am using the rowUpdating method as described in the blog, but the exception forces my code to stop the code in visual studio (like you would at a break point) and displays the message. Once I click play again, the code carries on and the program continues.

How do I stop the application from stopping once the exception has been called and carry on. Is there another way to do this?

[ASPxGridView FAQ: How to Enable Editing](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2007/08/30/aspxgridview-faq-how-to-enable-editing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Data Editing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3712). There is also a [link](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4610) about Validating data on the same page.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I needed to ensure the data being submitted corresponded to information in the database which needed to be done programmatically. [Here is the tutorial I used](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3747)